# Validar todos os inputs no SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma função que valida meus campos no evento `focusout`, porém, agora preciso percorrer todos os campos no `submit` do `form`, sei que deveria usar um `for`, mas não sei como.

```
$("input[type='text'],textarea").focusout(function () {
    validar($(this))
});

$("#formcontato").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //O for entraria aqui?
});

$('input, textarea').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && validar()) {
        request();
        return false;
    }
});

function request() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "minha api...",
        method: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            //antesEnvio();
        },
        success: function () {
            //sucessoRequest();
        },
        error: function () {
            //erroRequest();
        }
    });
}


function validar(input) {
    var valido = false;
    if (input.attr("id") === "email") {
        var filtro = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
        if (filtro.test(input.val())) {
            input.css("border-color", "green");
        } else {
            input.css("border-color", "red");
            valido = false;
        }
    }
    else if (input.val() === "") {
        input.css("border-color", "red");
        valido = false;
    }
    else if (input.val() != "") {
        input.css("border-color", "green");
    }

    return valido;
}
```

Comment: Uma forma fácil é definir variáveis globais com o valor false para cada validação, caso passem irão recebendo true, na hora do submit basta verificar se todas estão true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo o mesmo padrão de validação que vc está usando agora, digo para fazer o seguinte:

Primeiro vc deve fazer sua função **validar()** retornar true sempre que o campo estiver OK, e continuar retornando false quando algo estiver errado no preenchimento do campo.

Depois é só colocar o código abaixo no submit do seu form.

Ficaria assim:

```
$("#formcontato").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var success =[],
        inputs = this.elements;

    for (var i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++ {
        success.push(validar($(inputs[i])));
    }

    if (success.indexOf(false) >= 0) {
        return;
    }

    this.submit();
});
```

Explicando o que fiz:

A variável **success** é um array. A cada loop do for a função **validar()** vai retornar true ou false (se o campo estiver ok ou não), e esse retorno sempre é inserido na variável array success através do método push().

O método **push()** serve para inserirmos um novo valor no final de um array.

Ou seja, ao final do loop nosso array estará preenchido com vários **true** e **false**.

Seguindo...

O método indexOf() serve para buscarmos em um array um determinado valor. Se ele encontra o valor passado como argumento ele retorna a posição dentro do array (índice) onde o valor se encontra. Se ele NÃO encontra ele simplesmente retorna o valor **-1**.

No nosso caso eu verifico se no array success existe algum FALSE. Se tiver, eu interrompo o script antes de chamar o submit() manualmente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me salvou. Mas poderia me explicar a função? Minhas dúvidas são o que esses trechos:                              success.push(validar($(inputs[i])));   ------ success.indexOf(false) >= 0

Comment: @TiagoSilveira, editei a minha resposta para sanar suas dúvidas. :)

Answer (score 3):

Para validar texto e e-mail no submit você pode combinar o `type` mais `required` do HTML5 que ele não irá permitir a submissão se o dado for inválido.

**Exemplo**

```html
<form>
    <input type="email" required>E-mail
    <br>
    <input type="text" required>Texto
    <br>
    <input type="submit">Enviar
</form>
```